# Export SQL table containing XML data type from SQL to SQL using SSIS

Tags: ssis-2012

G'day all. We have a very large table in SQL 2005 containing over 200m records and one of the column is a XML data type. We are upgrading that database to SQL 2012 and hence the data need to be transferred across. For large db's (> 500 GB) we have figured out using SSIS is faster when compared to other traditional methods.

The question is, is there a faster way to transfer the table containing xml data type other than mapping the OLEDB Source to OLEDB Destination using SSIS?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Take the backup in SQL server 2005 and restore that backup in sql server 2012 or you can take the help of SQL server 2012 upgrade advisor before migrating the DB to find out the potential conflicts.